# A basic question regarding a rational function on a locally Noetherian scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be a field, $A = k[x,y] / (y^2, xy)$. I know that the ideals $P = (x-1)$ and $Q = (x-3)$ are maximal ideals in A, so $U = $ Spec $A \backslash \{ P, Q \}$ is an open subset of Spec $A$. Then it turns out that
$$
\frac{x-2}{(x-1)(x-3)}
$$
is an element of $\Gamma (U , O_{Spec \ A})$ and it is a rational function.

Could someone please explain me why this is a rational function? (I am reading the explanation in the notes by Ravi Vakil, but I am getting confused. Perhaps I am missing something easy...)

ps I would also appreciate if someone could explain me how this is an element of $\Gamma (U , O_{Spec \ A})$. I am a bit confused about this also.. Thank you!

Comment: That it is an element of $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A})$ follows from how Vakil defines $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A})$ in the notes would make it $A_{(x-1),(x-3)}$, that is the localization with those two elements invertible

Comment: Also by Vakil's definition in the notes, to conclude it is a rational function, you only need to know that $U$ contains all the associated points of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. What are the associated points and does it contain all of them?

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!