# Showing that some function is not a rational function on Spec $A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be a field, $A = k[x,y] / (y^2, xy)$. I know that the only associated points of 
Spec $A$ are $[(x,y)]$ and $[(y)]$. I want to show that
$$
\frac{x-2}{(x-1)x}
$$
is not a rational function.

Intuitively it makes sense to me that this function is not defined at
the origin $[(x,y)]$, hence not a rational function. But I am having trouble arguing it precisely. I would appreciate any comments. Thank you!

ps I apologize as this question is similar to my previous question
to show something is regular.
[A basic question regarding a rational function on a locally Noetherian scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162507/a-basic-question-regarding-a-rational-function-on-a-locally-noetherian-scheme)

Comment: Beware that Vakil's definition of rational function is not the standard one used in EGA or de Jong et al.'s Stack Project. In the standard definition any regular function defined on any dense open subset defines a rational function, without any mention of associated points.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I was not aware of that, thank you. Could you possibly explain me what does it exactly mean by $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$? Presumably we are assuming that it is an element of $\Gamma(V, O_{Spec A})$ for some open $V$, but when $V$ is not a distinguished open set, which element of the section does it mean by $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$? I think this might be one source of confusion for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the the fact that this function should be defined on the open set $U=\operatorname{Spec}A_{x,(x-1)}$ (inverting $x$ and $x-1$) or on a smaller open set so that $x$ and $x-1$ can be invertible. However such $U$ could not contain all the associated points of the scheme (which is necessary in Vakil's definition of rational section). For instance the origin is an associated point (by exercise 5.5A in Vakil's notes) and $U$ does not contain the origin, so indeed $\frac{x-2}{(x-1)x}$ cannot be a rational function

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Could you possibly explain me what does it exactly mean by $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$? Presumably we are assuming that it is an element of $\Gamma(V, O_{Spec A})$ for some open $V$, but when $V$ is not a distinguished open set, which element of the section does it mean by $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$?

Comment: Basically by rational function, we need a function in some open set that contains all the associated points. Basically $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$ will then be a function in any $V$ that does not contain the origin or $1$, and those are the only open sets for which it will be a function as you need $x$ and $x-1$ invertible.

Comment: For instance $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$ is a perfectly welldefined function on the distinguished open $\operatorname{Spec} A_{x(x-1)}$. Also if $V$ is a not a distinguished open, it should still be a subset of $\operatorname{Spec} A_{x(x-1)}$ for that function to be well-defined, so you can think of $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$ to be the image of $(x-2)/(x(x-1))$ under the restriction map

Comment: I see. Thank you again!